# AWS EKS - Authenticate Kubernetes python lib from inside a pod

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-eks

### Objective

I want to connect to and call Kubernetes REST APIs from inside a running pod, the Kubernetes in question is an AWS EKS cluster using IAM authentication. All of this using Kubernetes Python lib.

### What I have tried

From inside my `python file`:

```
from kubernetes import client, config

config.load_incluster_config()
v1 = client.CoreV1Api()
ret = v1.list_pod_for_all_namespaces(watch=False)
```

The above command throws a `403` error, This I believe is due to the different auth mechanism that AWS EKS uses.

### What I already know works

```
ApiToken = 'eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6IiJ9.xxx.yyy'
    configuration = client.Configuration()
    configuration.host = 'https://abc.sk1.us-east-1.eks.amazonaws.com'
    configuration.verify_ssl = False
    configuration.debug = True
    configuration.api_key = {"authorization": "Bearer " + ApiToken}
    client.Configuration.set_default(configuration)
```

While the above works, I have to hardcode a token that I generate locally via kubectl and check it into the code which is a security risk.

Is there a more proper way to authenticate the Kubernetes python lib with AWS EKS?

Answer (score 3):

You can use the following method to get the token. This assumes that you have successfully installed and configured [aws-iam-authenticator](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/install-aws-iam-authenticator.html) on your pod/server/laptop.

```
def get_token(cluster_name):
    args = ("/usr/local/bin/aws-iam-authenticator", "token", "-i", cluster_name, "--token-only")
    popen = subprocess.Popen(args, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    popen.wait()
    return popen.stdout.read().rstrip()

api_token = get_token("<cluster_name>")
configuration = client.Configuration()
configuration.host = '<api_endpoint>'
configuration.verify_ssl = False
configuration.debug = True
configuration.api_key['authorization'] = "Bearer " + api_token
configuration.assert_hostname = True
configuration.verify_ssl = False
client.Configuration.set_default(configuration)

v1 = client.CoreV1Api()
ret = v1.list_pod_for_all_namespaces(watch=False)
print ret
```

There is an PR for kubernetes-client/python-base that adds support for exec plugins, [Attempt to implement exec-plugins support in kubeconfig](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/python-base/pull/75).

Comment: Thanks, I will test it out in some time and mark / reply accordingly. Appreciate it.

Comment: I bashed into the pod and checked, there is no aws-iam-authenticator folder in the location that you wrote, I imagine something needs to be installed for that to appear. Can you point me in the right direction?

Comment: https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/aws-iam-authenticator. The pod or instance that it's running on has to be signed a role that allows the application to list pods in all namespaces. You should, however, be able to do this with an SA. It's not necessary to use IAM if the application is running in the cluster.

Comment: You need to define AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID and AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY environment variables for aws-iam-authenticator to work. This might be obvious to users familiar with the tooling, but was not obvious to me. The error message didn't help me out much: "could not get token: NoCredentialProviders: no valid providers in chain. Deprecated."